# Python - Splitting the response of a non-json request

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, split, python-requests

Basically, I'm using an API and sending requests to it.
The response doesn't come in json, so I am not being able to read it properly.

The response comes "plain":

```
RANDO:284420457:79065331589
```

What I have tried was the `r.text()` but haven't been able to make it still work. Basically I'd like to have the information splitted by the `:` and each of them going into a different variable.

```
    r = requests.get(url=URL, verify=False)
    data = r.text()

    data = data.split(":")
    var0 = data[0]
    var1 = data[1]
    var2 = data[2]
```

var0 would be `RANDO`
var1 `284420457`
var2 `79065331589`

Error at r.text(): `Command raised an exception: TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`

Comment: Sorry, just trying to clarify. Its `r.text()` that you are having issues with? That's what is erroring for you? Can you paste the error that you get when you do `r.text()`

Comment: Command raised an exception: TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Comment: it should be `r.text` not `r.text()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this (note it's `r.text` not `r.text()`):

```
r = requests.get(url=URL, verify=False)
data = r.text

vars = {'var'+str(i): value for i, value in enumerate(data.split(":"))}
print(vars)
```

Output:

```
{'var0': 'RANDO', 'var1': '284420457', 'var2': '79065331589'}
```

Comment: Still getting the same error as I was: `Command raised an exception: TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`

Comment: Can you clarify which part of the code is giving this error?

Comment: My bad, was using text() instead of text

Comment: Please accept the answer if you're happy with it, thanks!